# win32 strawberry perl PAR Packer make exe file

Tags: windows, perl, par, perl-packager

i use on windows server :
Summary of my perl5 (revision 5 version 30 subversion 0) configuration
PAR::Packer is up to date (1.049).

I can successfully build an exe file without error message.

pp -o p.exe p.pl

content p.pl

```
use warnings;
use strict;
print "This is the Perl code!\n";
```

on the local machine run fine. Transfer the exe to other windows host and run script. No output :-(

What am I doing wrong?

Regards
Thomas

Comment: What operating system is the local machine?

Comment: I have also faced the similar issue. Put '$| = 1'at the top of print in perl script and after that make exe. Hopefully it will worked. You print data is in output buffer. More info https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html (look for $|)

Comment: Please check the size of the **exe** file -- it might be that some library is not available on **other machine** or some critical piece is missing.

Comment: Hey Maverick, wonderful, you saved my day - when you are in germany - you are welcome . That was the solution. Thanx again from an old unix men.