# How do I debug an executable created using the perl PAR packager (pp)?

Tags: perl, debugging, pp-perl-par-packager

I've used the [PAR packager (pp)](https://metacpan.org/pod/pp) to create a Windows executable `foo.exe` from a Perl script `foo.pl`.  The Perl script runs fine (`perl foo.pl <arguments>`).  The executable runs, too (`foo.exe <arguments>`), but doesn't produce the same results as the Perl script.  I want to debug the perl script as run by the executable, to figure out where the difference comes from.  How do I do that?  In other words, how do I pass a `-d` to the `perl.exe` that starts when I execute `foo.exe`?

**ADDENDUM 2020-05-26**

Using "Process Explorer" I found the application that ends up getting executed.  It was `%TEMP%\par-<ID1>\cache-<ID2>\foo.exe`, where `<ID1>` and `<ID2>` are short and long hexadecimal strings.  I had hoped to find `...\perl.exe foo.pl` instead, then I could have injected my `-d` into the command line.

Running `foo.exe` in that folder yields an error "Can't locate PAR.pm in @INC".

That same folder also contains numerous *.pm, *.dll (including perl528.dll), and a few *.pl files, with the *.pl and *.pm files having names that are short hexadecimal strings.  One of the *.pl files (the one mentioned in the process's PAR_0 environment variable) turns out to have the same contents as `foo.pl`, with the following two lines prefixed:

```
package main;
#line 1 "script/foo.pl"
```

If I run `perl -Iinc/lib <ID>.pl` in that folder, with `<ID>.pl` the name of that perl script, then it produces the desired results, i.e., doesn't run into the problem that the exe runs into.  I expect that the perl528.dll and other dlls in that folder are the bits that make up Perl, but don't know how to call them.  The `foo.exe` in that folder is only 78 kB in size, so it cannot do much more than have those other bits do the work.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems it is not possible to pass `-d` option to the `perl.exe`. Maybe try add a request for this feature at [the GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/rschupp/PAR-Packer/issues)?  In any case you could always try debugging by adding `print` statements at selected points in your code..

Comment: What is the result you are expecting? Is it some 'print' statement ? Take a look at - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58817812/win32-strawberry-perl-par-packer-make-exe-file . It's one of common issue. you have to write $| =1 at top.

Comment: @Håkon Hægland: I was hoping to avoid "debugging-by-print".

Comment: @Maverick: Your suggestion made no difference, unfortunately.  The exe and pl both produce output, but the exe seems to hang while the pl continues producing output and quickly completes.